FPB-RA0E1 Flash overflow error with CMSIS FFT library
I am working on an embedded project with the FPB-RA0E1 microcontroller using e2 studio. My goal is to perform an FFT on ADC input data and transmit the results over UART. I am utilizing the ARM CMSIS-DSP library for the FFT processing.
Here are the details of my project:
Microcontroller: FPB-RA0E1
Toolchain: E2 studio IDE with FSP version 5.6.0
Compiler: GCC ARM Embedded 13.2.1.arm-13-7
CMSIS-DSP: Using arm_rfft_fast_f32 and arm_rfft_init_f32 for FFT calculations
Peripherals: ADC (with DMA) and UART

The issue arises when I try to compile the project. I receive the following error:
Extracting support files...
13:43:21 **** Incremental Build of configuration Debug for project CMSIS_FFT_Dummy ****
make -r -j8 all 
Building target: CMSIS_FFT_Dummy.elf
C:/Users/1064238/AppData/Local/Programs/Renesas/RA/e2studio_v2024-10_fsp_v5.6.0/toolchains/gcc_arm/13.2.rel1/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/13.2.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld.exe: CMSIS_FFT_Dummy.elf section `.text' will not fit in region `FLASH'
C:/Users/1064238/AppData/Local/Programs/Renesas/RA/e2studio_v2024-10_fsp_v5.6.0/toolchains/gcc_arm/13.2.rel1/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/13.2.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld.exe: region `FLASH' overflowed by 16876 bytes
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [makefile:111: CMSIS_FFT_Dummy.elf] Error 1
"make -r -j8 all" terminated with exit code 2. Build might be incomplete.

13:43:25 Build Failed. 3 errors, 0 warnings. (took 3s.910ms)

Could you please help me to resolve it
